# Filtering tuples in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

(Python 2.7, Windows)

hello all, I have a list containing tuples and I want to filter out the "(0,0,35)":

```
a_list = [(0,0,35), (0,0,35), (9,12,12), (0,0,35), (5,12,6)]

for element in a_list:
    if element is not "(0,0,35)":
        print element
```

it does't work.

Can you show me the right way? thanks.

Comment: `if element is not "(0,0,35)":` is comparing a tuple, which is an object in Python, to a string. Even though they might look the same at face value, they are different types of objects, and they are represented differently in memory, so they will never be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work, because tuples cannot be represented as strings.

```
>>> (0, 0, 35) == "(0, 0, 35)"
False
>>>
```

Also, use `!=` instead of `is not` because `==` tests for equality (the prefix `!` tests for **in**equality), but `is` tests for the **`id`** being the same (the `not` checks for the **`id`** not being the same).

```
>>> x = (0, 0, 35)
>>> x is (0, 0, 35)
False
>>> x == (0, 0, 35)
True
>>> id(x)
4299863136
>>> id((0, 0, 35))
4299863216
>>>
```

Try this:

```
a_list = [(0,0,35), (0,0,35), (9,12,12), (0,0,35), (5,12,6)]

for element in a_list:
    if element != (0,0,35):
        print element
```

Comment: thanks, To Click or Not to Click. seems all you 3 answer at the same time so I am happily chooses your the most details as the best.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because you are testing against the string `"(0,0,35)"` which is not the same as the tuple `(0,0, 35)`. This should work:

```
a_list = [(0,0,35), (0,0,35), (9,12,12), (0,0,35), (5,12,6)]

for element in a_list:
    if element != (0,0,35):
        print element
```

A better solution would probably be to construct the filtered list using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a_list = [(0,0,35), (0,0,35), (9,12,12), (0,0,35), (5,12,6)]
filtered_list = [e for e in a_list if e != (0,0,35)]
```

Comment: thanks, Thibaut. hope you don't mind I choose the most detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
[ x for x in a_list if x != (0,0,35) ]
```

demo:

```
>>> (1,2,3) == '(1,2,3)'
False
>>> str((1,2,3)) == '(1,2,3)'
False
>>> (1,2,3) == (1,2,3)
True
```

even if you force it to str ti will result in false

Comment: An explanation would help the OP.

Comment: thanks, Hackaholic. hope you don't mind I choose the most detailed answer.